# How can I prevent my SESSION from being overwritten on pageLoad of my MasterPage?

Tags: asp.net, session

I'm new to asp world, and I have to keep my new job :)
Switching form php to asp.net 3.5 (never used before). 
What would be the best practice for storing a SESSION variable in my project ?

How can I prevent my SESSION to be overwritten if my initialisation code is in the onPageLoad method of my MasterPage ?

My variables keeps beeing overwritten, please someone help me and tell me if there is any other solution than dealing with this pageLoad problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, if your session values are getting lost... there must be something wrong. That totally defeats the purpose of having sessions!

You can try a couple of articles and get better understanding of this...

http://aspalliance.com/1182

http://blogs.msdn.com/rahulso/archive/2007/01/17/troubleshooting-cookies-a-case-study.aspx

HTH

Comment: My pleasure Darkyo! Did you find the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Session["account"] == null) {
Session["account"] = GetAccount();
}
```

Comment: Seems so obvious but truely works ! 
I heard that Global.asax could do the trick too , I think i'll have to dig there

Answer (score 0):

You can always check that if the Session value exists or not.

```
if(Session["UserName"] == null) 
{
   Session["UserName"] = User.Identity.UserName; 
}
```